# How do I get an Access Token? - PayPal in Flutter

Tags: paypal, flutter

I have faced the issue like get access token in PayPal using flutter

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function. hope it can work.

```
Future makePost() async {
String username = "*************";
String password = "*************";
var bytes = utf8.encode("$username:$password");
var credentials = base64.encode(bytes);
Map token = {
'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
};

 var headers = {
 "Accept": "application/json",
 'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
 "Authorization": "Basic $credentials"
  };

 var url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
 var requestBody = token;
 http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: requestBody, headers: headers);
 var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
 return responseJson;
}
```